# GIT: Merge two branches using netbeans

Tags: git, version-control, netbeans, merge, branch

I have two *branches* created at [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/anyulled/sisco/), one called ***master*** and another called  ***modulo-contratos***.

The thing is that the second branch has changes in some files that I need to integrate into ***master***, but when I do a *merge* using **Netbeans** for it, it replaces my newest files in ***master*** with the older ones from the ***modulo-contratos*** branch.

What could I do?

Answer (score 3):

For git, the files from `modulo-contratos` must look "newer" than the ones in `master`. You probably edited them in the `modulo-contratos` branch after updating them in `master`.

You have several options:

1. Try to checkout `modulo-contratos` and merge with `master` (instead of the other way around). That might give better results.
2. Create a patch using the `modulo-contratos` branch and apply that to `master`. After that, merge and revert all changed files by replacing them with the version that you had before. This way, your `master` branch will be clean and the "time stamps" will be reset for the next round (so this won't happen again).

Comment: the first option didn't work. All I have left is to do the merging manually.

Comment: You should spend some time to figure out what you did to break the merge, too, so it doesn't happen again.